# Why can't php pthread modify an object?

Tags: php

I'm using php5.4, and wirte the following code for test. I pass an object to a worker thread, and try to modify the object in the thread, which doesn'g work as expected.

```
<?php

class WorkerThread extends Thread {

    var $foo = null;

    public function __construct($foo) {
        $this->foo = $foo;
    }   

    public function run() {
        echo "thread started.\n";
        $this->foo->val = 2;
        echo "\n";
        echo $this->foo->val;
        echo "\n";
        echo "thread exit${val}.\n";
    }   

}   

class A {
    var $val = 1;
}   

$foo = new A();

var_dump($foo);

$thread = new WorkerThread($foo);
$thread->start();
sleep(1);

var_dump($foo);

$foo2 = $foo;
$foo2->val = 3;

var_dump($foo);

?>
```

This is the output I get:

```
object(A)#1 (1) {
  ["val"]=>
  int(1)
}
thread started.

1  # I expect 2 here
thread exit.
object(A)#1 (1) {
  ["val"]=>
  int(1)    # I expect 2 here
}
object(A)#1 (1) {   # as expected
  ["val"]=>
  int(3)
}
```

If I can't share objects between thread, What is the mutex, cond designed for?

Comment: That's interesting. Do you run it from the command line? 
No warning or other messages from PHP in the logs when you run that?

Comment: @ringo I run it from command line, didn't get any warning.